# How to generate dynamic path value for a graphql query response using GraphQL.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, graphql-dotnet

I have REST API (**api/tax/v1/countries**) with the following response. In the below the pngimagePath and svgimagePath properties are pointing to the image type endpoints(**api/tax/v1/country/Country1/{FlagPNG or FlagSVG}**)

The paths are generated dynamically in this case.

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "pngimagePath": "https://test.com/api/tax/v1/country/Country1/4/image/FlagPNG",
      "svgimagePath": "https://test.com/api/tax/v1/country/Country1/405/image/FlagSVG",
      "displayName": "Country1",
      "displayNameShort": "Country1",
      "providerName": "Testing",
      "providerTerms": null,
      "uuid": "1",
      "name": "Country1",
      "path": "Country1",
      "completeResponse": true
    },
    {
      "pngimagePath": "https://test.com/api/tax/v1/country/Country2/5/image/FlagPNG",
      "svgimagePath": "https://test.com/api/tax/v1/country/Country2/406/image/FlagSVG",
      "displayName": "Country2",
      "displayNameShort": "Country2",
      "providerName": "Testing one",
      "providerTerms": null,
      "uuid": "2",
      "name": "Country2",
      "path": "Country2",
      "completeResponse": true
    }
  ],  
  "authorised": false,
  "userMessage": ""
}



 // Code to generate the image path
var apiPath = _appSettings.Value.ApiPath + "country/";
result.Countries.AddRange(rawCountries.Select(country  =>  new DTO.CountryDTO {
PNGImagePath =  $"{apiPath}{Helper.ReplaceChars(country.DefaultDisplayName)}/{country.PngImageId}/image/{country.PngImageType}" ,  SVGImagePath =  $"{apiPath}{Helper.ReplaceChars(country.DefaultDisplayName)}/{country.SvgImageId}/image/{country.SvgImageType}" ,  } ) ) ;
```

I want to generate the image path using GraphQL.NET.

Can anyone help me to know how to implement this feature

Comment: What do you mean by generate image path? Does `api/tax/v1/countries` call `GraphQL.NET`? Have you used `GraphQL.NET` or you want to migrate web api to it?

Comment: I am in the process of migrating the existing REST APIs to GraphQL endpoint using GraphQL.NET. In the existing response as mentioned in my query there is "pngimagePath": "https://test.com/api/tax/v1/country/Country1/4/image/FlagPNG" and "svgimagePath": "https://test.com/api/tax/v1/country/Country1/405/image/FlagSVG". As part of the graphql response for this query I also need to expose these properties also. Can you please help me to know how to accomplish this implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `pngimagePath` which is generated based on `country`, you could define a new field with `resolve` to generate the value for `pngimagePath`.

```
    public class PlayerType : ObjectGraphType<Player>
{
    public PlayerType(ISkaterStatisticRepository skaterStatisticRepository)
    {
        Field(x => x.Id);
        Field(x => x.Name, true);
        Field(x => x.BirthPlace);
        Field(x => x.Height);
        Field(x => x.WeightLbs);


        Field<StringGraphType>("pngimagePath", resolve: context => $"{context.Source.Name} {context.Source.BirthDate} {context.Source.BirthPlace}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much for your inputs :). It helped me a lot. I will implement it.